# RSS feed reader. QT. Troubles

Tags: c++, qt, rss, qt5, qthttp

I was reading this tutorial:
http://www.tuxradar.com/content/code-project-create-qt-rss-reader
and tried to create RSS feed reader in QT Creator.
As this article was wrote a years ago, I met a problems (see on img. or visit URL):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jfkoUAwYVhQTlOdGVjdS1sbDQ/edit?usp=sharing
As I understand: the whole problem in that, that "QHttpResponseHeader" and "QHttp" is too old and do not using for years in QT. I don't know how to fix that problem, though I tried.
**How to fix a problem?**
My project (with inline editor to open "h" and "cpp" files): http://1drv.ms/1njxfIy
[image: Issues]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add this to your project file:

```
QT += http
```

and you need to install the corresponding add-on module from [either here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qthttp/source/36f370ac28c5864da5bc1cbd61980e053c1cb4c9%3a) or your package distributor.

Comment: I, already, trying for 2 hours to install that module. How can I do this?

Comment: @PavloZvarych: `git clone git@gitorious.org:qt/qthttp.git && cd qthttp && qmake -r && nmake && nmake install` if you happen to use msvc.

Comment: Got a few problems. Some problems I already resolved, but this one, - unfortunately, - no: "Project ERROR addExclusiveBuilds() requires at least two arguments".

Comment: @PavloZvarych: I do not know how that is related to the question.

Comment: it's all about solving project problems. This "Project ERROR ..." message I got in Git Bash while trying to install add-on module. Any way, thank you for efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with the solution, I tried modify some steps. First of all I put the sequency into bash

```
 sudo git clone git://gitorius.org/qt/qthttp.git
 cd qthttp/
 sudo qmake -r
 sudo make
 sudo make install
```

Its the same solution of Final Contest. So, with that the problem for me continued. In the code of tuxradar.com I replaces in the .pro file the sequency

```
 QT       += xml\
          network\
          webkitwidgets\
          http\

 greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

The rest of the code (.pro) still the same. Into .h file I replaces `#include <QGui/QMainWindow>` by `#include <QMainWindow>` and I insert `#include <QHttp>` 
`#include <QUrl>`. Was that, sorry by my english. :)